# SharePoint list column is hidden in content type but get_hidden() returns false

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, jsom

I am using a custom form `CustomForm.aspx` in place of `NewForm.aspx` for a list,

From content type of list I have set the field(column) as **Hidden** 
but using JSOM `get_hidden()` returns `false`

What can I do to get the actual status of field if it is hidden or not.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and check the field on the content type instead:

```
(function(ctx) {
    var field = ctx.get_web().getList(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Tasks").get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("StartDate");
    var ctField = ctx.get_web().getList(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/Lists/Tasks").get_contentTypes().getById("0x010800F6B0BE8B7684574F82A6FCC51E1D8A37").get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("StartDate");
    ctx.load(ctField, "Hidden")
    ctx.load(field, "Hidden");

    ctx.executeQueryAsync( function() { 
          console.log(ctField.get_hidden());
          console.log(field.get_hidden())
    }, function(s,a) { console.log(a.get_message()) })
})( SP.ClientContext.get_current() )
```

Comment: Thanks, it would slow down a bit, but I will try.

Comment: @codemirror yeah, you probably have to set it to hidden with code. When you use hide with the GUI you are doing it on the CT i recon.  field.set_hidden("true");